# Proof of Chow's Lemma, where is proper necessary?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, noetherian

I am looking at Wikipeda for the proof of [Chow's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow's_lemma). My impression is that the proof uses $X$ is a separated scheme over a Noetherian scheme $S$ (throughout where it is argued that some graph map is a closed immersion we would only need $X$ is separated over $S$). At first glance I do not see where $X$ is separated over $S$ is not sufficient to use this proof. Could someone point out to me where "proper" is necessary and separated is not sufficient? I wouldn't dare ask for an example where the Lemma is not true if $X$ were just separated over $S$. But if you feel ambitious ... :)

**Edit:** It seems to me that the proof in Wikipedia is not very precise. I think I know what's going on now. We just need the fact that $X$ is finite type over $S$ (but proper is not really needed), at least this is the impression I get when I looked at the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02O2)

Comment: The result is not true if $X$ is only assumed finite type and separated: take $S$ to be the spectrum of a field $k$ and $X$ to be the affine line over a field. No projective variety over $k$ surjects onto $X$.

Comment: In fact, it is never true if $X$ is only assumed to be finite type and separated. You should try to prove: If $X$ is finite type separated over $S$ and $f:X'\to X$ a surjective map with $X'$ proper over $S$, then $X$ is proper over $S$.

Answer (score 5):

The proof in Wikipedia is awfully written at the end (what is $v$?, what is $U′$?) and the problem is in this last part. Using the notation of Wikipedia, you can prove (without properness of $X$) that the map $g:X'\rightarrow P$ is a locally closed immersion. Hence you get Chow lemma without the properness hypothesis but only with a quasi-projective domain in the birrational surjective map.

But if moreover $X$ is proper then
$$q_1:X\times_S P\rightarrow P$$
is a closed map, hence $g=q_1|_{X'}$ is a closed immersion and you get that $X'$ is projective. In order to see the entire proof written carefully look at the EGA reference provided there ( EGA II Theorem 5.6.1).